# php phalcon use composer autoload.php not working

Tags: php, datatables, phalcon

I want to use a class that installs by composer, but I don't get an error that the class does not exist.
use the file_exists to check if the file is being loaded but I always get false.
apparently composer's autoload.php is not importing into phalcon's loader.php either.

i install this
https://github.com/m1ome/phalcon-datatables
this is the order of my folders, in the vendor folder is the autoload.php

app/

-- config/

-- controllers/

-- models/

-- view/

-- config/

public/

vendor/

Answer (score 2):

You need to `require()` Composer's auto-loader - Phalcon won't do that for you.  You could add the line in your bootstrap file, or even in the `public/index.php` file.